# highcharts import/export JSON

Tags: highcharts

I'm working with a dashboard from Highcharts and I cannot figure out how to make importing for JSON work. Right now exporting basic dashboard layout into a JSON works (I cannot use localStorage, it has to be an external JSON), I've tried a few times but I'm kinda lost.

Tried working with Highcharts documentation yet I'm still really lost. After implementing a button for import and importing it once, the export button stopped working and does not export a new JSON for that page instance so I just have to reload it. If anyone has such an implementation that works I would be really glad.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Here's an official Highcharts Dashboards **[demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/dashboards/exporting/export-to-localstorage/)** showing a simple implementation of the import/export logic.

In short: if you want to create a new Dashboards from your JSON config, you call: `Dashboards.board('container', JSON.parse(stringifiedJSON));` and when you want to get a full JSON config of your Dashboard, you can call `dashboard.getOptions()`.

Then, you can use these options to store them in localStorage, cookies, or a database after stringifying it with `JSON.stringify(dashboard.getOptions())`.

Please let me know in case anything's unclear. You should be able to store the stringified dashboard options in local storage with no problems, and if you do have any problems please try to reproduce this issue in an online code editor so I can take a look and investigate this.